# remove space between custom cell and border tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

Please tell me how to remove space between border of custom cell and border of uitableview. I am using iPhone5 with width = 640px => boarder uitableview = 640px. How to set width of custom cell = 640px.

[image]

i want to remove space from left and right.

Comment: What are the constraints for your prototype cell?  Did you constrain to the margin, or use a non-zero leading/trailing space?

Comment: @PetahChristian my custom cell constraints - label (category), label(title), label(subtitle) and imageView(avatar)  - this is news application. I want the right and left no space. I use everywhere zero.

Comment: When you view the constraints, are they set to `Superview.Leading` or to `Superview.Leading Margin`?